# why do I need "sealed" method if "virtual" is required in order to allow derived class override it?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

or am I missing something basic here??..

since sealed method avoids it to be overridden in the derived class and virtual allows it to

Comment: What makes you think you *need* sealed?

Comment: in my understanding, one excludes another, trying to figure out why even sealed method exists

Comment: You could use `sealed` to prevent a derived class from implementing a method.

Comment: I don't understand the +4 for the first comment, the point of the question is to see the different between the method keyword and not apply an scenario which would question if sealed is required or not

Comment: @EdwinSoho, On why +4 to comment: Have you read title of your question? "why do I need sealed..." - to most people it clearly says that there is some reason that **you** need to specify "sealed". It is not clear that the question actually is about usage of these 2 keywords in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `virtual` keyword will let you (or someone using your code) override a given method with their own logic.
2. The `abstract` keyword will force you (or someone else using your code) to override it with your own logic.
3. The `sealed` keyword will let you (or someone using your code) prevent any further modification of a method.

**An overriden method can be overriden again if you don't add "sealed".**

When you think of these keywords, think of both scenarios: you can code for yourself, or you can create DLLs and code libraries for others to use. The latter scenario will often warrant the use of sealed, abstract and virtual.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you mean, in a first derived class, where one method from base class is virtual, and the second level overrides it and apply sealed, in order to no other class(third level) could override it. Is that so?

Comment: Yup! And abstract (on first level) will force an override.

Comment: that makes perfect sense... trying to compile all the information here..give me a moment.

Answer (score 6):

`sealed` is for preventing a subclass from overriding `virtual` methods you overrode.

Comment: That could be explained a lot more clearly.  Since there are at least three classes involved, subclass is ambiguous.  And it's your method, not the method you overrode, that gets sealed.

Comment: although your answer was the first one and explains what I need, I'm picking Joe's answer since it contains more details in order to make it easier to understand for a future user looking for the same answer for my question. Thanks

Comment: @EdwinSoho: No worries, glad you found your answer.

Comment: @Joe: It's to prevent a subclass from overriding a method *you overrode*... in this case, marking method G as sealed would prevent a subclass of you (class C) from overriding the method, which you overrode.

Comment: @Joe: Read what I wrote again... it says it *would prevent a **subclass of you (class C)** from overriding method G*. You never subclassed C here. If someone later decides to subclass C then it will certainly matter whether or not you sealed anything in it.

Comment: Oops, my bad. In fact the answer I was looking for is "you can override an override if you don't add sealed". :) Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Methods do **not** to be `sealed` or `virtual`. You do not need to specify anything, which will in turn **not** let derived classes override them.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>Methods can me virtual, but only classes can be sealed.</strike>
Sealed classes can not be inherited from.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw(v=vs.71).aspx

EDIT:
Ok, I was wrong, a method can be sealed, but only one that already overrides another, the keyword then prevents further overriding of the method.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: methods can be sealed as well, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx